# Discord JS command not being proccesed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been working on a moderation bot in Discord.JS recently, and I've completed many commands such as Purge, Mute, etc. As I was working on the 'ban' command, I noticed that I was getting no response from the bot. I started debugging, even restarted development on the command a couple times, and then, I thought to change the command to something basic to check if the bot was even receiving the command. So the command now just had `message.channel.send('hello world')`, and I ran the command, still no output, just when I use no arguments, a `Please provide arguments to execute this command` message. I then tried deleting the command file and restarting the bot, and I ran the command, same output. Ill include my bot.js below:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.permissions) {
        const authorPerms = message.channel.permissionsFor(message.author);
        if (!authorPerms || !authorPerms.has(command.permissions)) {
            return message.reply('You can not do this!');
        }
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `\`Please provide arguments to execute this command\``;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }

    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: can you show your ban command file?

Comment: I dont currently have a ban file, as i deleted it for testing purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an issue with discord rate limiting which can happen often if you attempt to login a bot many times over a short period of time. If the issue is just with that one ban command its either an issue with the ban command itself or your command handler. if its an issue with all commands, the `ready` event might not be being emitted which would indicate what I mentioned above. try using a different bot token or regenerating your current one and running the program again.